# Unresolved reference: search_src_text

Tags: android, searchview, dynamic-feature-module

## For reference

This is a branch showing the issue (**note the project is incomplete**). Run it and you'll see the compile time error `Unresolved reference: search_src_text`.

https://github.com/mitchtabian/Clean-Notes/blob/searchview-issue/notes/src/main/java/com/codingwithmitch/cleannotes/notes/framework/presentation/notelist/NoteListFragment.kt

## What I'm trying to do:

I want to submit text to my ViewModel from the SearchView. When the text is submitted I execute a query using that text.

## What you might be thinking:

> "Just use an `OnQueryTextListener`."

An `OnQueryTextListener` will not submit text if the text is null/empty. I am using the null/empty case to search everything in the database. So that doesn't work.

## The work-around I tried:

In the past I've manually searched for the id of the `SearchAutoComplete` view inside the SearchView. You can find it like this:

```kotlin
val searchPlate: SearchView.SearchAutoComplete? = search_view.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text)
```

Then you just attach an `OnEditorActionListener` and listen for the IME actions and you're good to go:

```kotlin
searchPlate.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED
        || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH ) {
        val searchQuery = v.text.toString()
        viewModel.setQuery(searchQuery)
        viewmodel.executeSearch()
    }
    true
}
```

Usually this works fine. The only difference (that I can see) is this time I'm using a **Dynamic Feature Module**. When trying to access `R.id.search_src_text` it throws this compile time error:

```
Unresolved reference: search_src_text
```

And yes, **the layout is in the dynamic feature module /res/ directory.**

## The code

**1. SearchView in layout**

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/app_background_color"
    >

   <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:queryHint="@string/text_Search"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**2. Get reference to search_src_text**

```kotlin
val searchPlate: SearchView.SearchAutoComplete? = search_view.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text)
```

**Running the project will yield the error `Unresolved reference: search_src_text`**.

## Another weird thing:

I looped through the View hierarchy until I found the SearchAutoComplete, then attached the listener and it works just fine...

```kotlin
for((index1, child) in search_view.children.withIndex()){
    printLogD("ListFragment", "${index1}, ${child}")
    for((index2, child2) in (child as ViewGroup).children.withIndex()){
        printLogD("ListFragment", "T2: ${index2}, ${child2}")
        if(child2 is ViewGroup){
            for((index3, child3) in (child2 as ViewGroup).children.withIndex()){
                printLogD("ListFragment", "T3: ${index3}, ${child3}")
                if(child3 is ViewGroup){
                    for((index4, child4) in (child3 as ViewGroup).children.withIndex()){
                        printLogD("ListFragment", "T4: ${index4}, ${child4}")
                        if(child4 is SearchView.SearchAutoComplete){
                            child4.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->
                                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED
                                    || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH ) {
                                    val searchQuery = v.text.toString()
                                    printLogD("NoteList", "SearchView: (keyboard or arrow) executing search...: ${searchQuery}")
                                    viewModel.setQuery(searchQuery).let{
                                        viewModel.loadFirstPage()
                                    }
                                }
                                true
                            }
                            break
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

```
val searchPlate: SearchView.SearchAutoComplete? = search_view.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)
```

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'R' for appcompat